# blackberry desktop will not prompt for install

Tags: system-installation

I have a torch 9810 and need to tether for my network  connection, i am totally new to xubuntu and have no idea of what to do next. also the installs kaffeine, parole and multimedia calls for plug ins. help me to understand please, im from windows and very lost.

Comment: Could you split this question into two: one for the blackberry, and another one for the multimedia? It would also help to include what you already did, and what messages the system showed to you.

Answer (score 1):

**Use LinBerry to manage your blackberry phone**

Here are some of the functions currently available in LinBerry:

- Manage Your Contacts
- Install/Uninstall Applications
- Backup/Restore Your Data (files, music, video, etc.)
- Turn Your Device Into A Modem To Connect To The Internet

The developer is intending to include the follwing functions in next LinBerry' updates:

- Software Updates (OS Upgrade)
- Wipe Out Your BlackBerry
- Sync Your BlackBerry With Thunderbird Lightning/Evolution
- More Language Support

**LinBerry Installation**

To install LinBerry on Ubuntu 11.10/12.04 via PPA, open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/mobile

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linberry -y
```

You can start LinBerry from the Unity Dash or from Application Menu

Enjoy!